# How to disable http options method in jetty server

Tags: jetty, war, http-method

I have inherited a war file that uses jetty. I want to disable HTTP methods options.

I'm not familiar with the jetty server. Please help me in disabling HTTP methods in step

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's supported by the standard Servlet spec.

Edit the war's `WEB-INF/web.xml` and add a security constraint against the url-patterns to reject `OPTIONS` method on.

Example.

```xml
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee 
  http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
  version="3.1">

  <!-- ... other configurations ... -->

  <security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
      <web-resource-name>Restricted HTTP Methods</web-resource-name>
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
      <http-method>OPTIONS</http-method>
      <http-method>TRACE</http-method>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint />
  </security-constraint>
</web-app>
```